# On the property of the "tail" of the Lebesgue integral

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I wish to prove that for every Lebesgue integrable function $h$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for all $x=(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ the following is true:

\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\int\limits_{|y|\geq N} |h(x-y)|\,dy=0,
\end{equation}
where $|y|=\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2+\dots+y_n^2}$.

Here are my thoughts. Let $h(y)$ is Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, obviously, $|h(y)|$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$. By the change of variables formula we have
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(x-y)|\,dy=
|\operatorname{Det}T|^{-1}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(t)|\,dt=
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(t)|\,dt,
\end{equation}
where $t=x-y$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\operatorname{Det}T$ is the determinant of the diagonal matrix
\begin{equation}
T=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & -1 & \dots & 0\\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots\\
0 & 0 & \dots & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
So that function $|h(x-y)|$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Next,
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(x-y)|\,dy=
\int\limits_{|y|<N}|h(x-y)|\,dy+\int\limits_{|y|\geq N}|h(x-y)|\,dy.
\end{equation}
It is clear that
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\int\limits_{|y|<N}|h(x-y)|\,dy=
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(x-y)|\,dy,
\end{equation}
whence it follows that the "tail" of the whole integral approaches to zero:
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\int\limits_{|y|\geq N}|h(x-y)|\,dy=0.
\end{equation}
Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Note that $|h|\mathbf{1}_{\{|h| \geq N\}} \leq |h|$ and since Lebesgue measure is also Haar measure, you can apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to conclude at once. (This is essentially your argument, which is overall correct, but yours seems complicated.)